# I can't access my root user

Tags: permissions, root

I am a new Ubuntu user and I am using Ubuntu 14.04. When I try to change root permissions, I get some error reports. I have already tried `sudo chown -R 777 /` and `sudo chmod -R 777 /`. Please help me if I am doing any mistakes. Is there any command to access my root folder or root user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo chmod -R 777 /` sounds like an **incredibly bad idea**. If you ran that command successfully, you will probably want to reinstall your system right away, since you made all your files accessible and executable.

Ubuntu systems don't have a root password by default for security reasons. Users in the `sudo` group can run any commands *as* root using the `sudo` command, but you should think twice, because you can (no, you **will**) break your system if you don't know what you're doing. If you really want a root shell, you can get one with `sudo su -`. You have been warned. To read more about how to use `sudo`, please refer to the [Official Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo).

About installing ruby1.8, that's a quite different question. Since ruby1.8 has been removed from the official repositories in 14.04, you will have to use a PPA [like this one](http://brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/).

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8
```

Check out the referenced website for further information.

Comment: while trying to install ruby1.8. It is showing "Package 'ruby1.8' has no installation candidate". please help me.

Comment: Thank you, here i install 1.8 successfully. but for the kind information, dont run the "sudo apt-get update".